# How can I tell kotlin that a function doesn't return null if the parameter is not null?

Tags: android, kotlin, nullable, static-analysis

I want to write a convenience extension to extract values from a Map while parsing them at the same time. If the parsing fails, the function should return a default value. This all works fine, but I want to tell the Kotlin compiler that when the default value is not null, the result won't be null either. I could to this in Java through the `@Contract` annotation, but it seems to not work in Kotlin. Can this be done? Do contracts not work for extension functions? Here is the kotlin attempt:

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract

private const val TAG = "ParseExtensions"

@Contract("_, !null -> !null")
fun Map<String, String>.optLong(key: String, default: Long?): Long? {
    val value = get(key)
    value ?: return default

    return try {
        java.lang.Long.valueOf(value)
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
        Log.e(TAG, e)
        Log.d(TAG, "Couldn't convert $value to long for key $key")

        default
    }
}

fun test() {
    val a = HashMap<String, String>()

    val something: Long = a.optLong("somekey", 1)
}
```

In the above code, the IDE will highlight an error in the assignment to `something` despite `optLong` being called with a non null default value of 1. For comparison, here is similar code which tests nullability through annotations and contracts in Java:

```
public class StackoverflowQuestion
{
    @Contract("_, !null -> !null")
    static @Nullable Long getLong(@NonNull String key, @Nullable Long def)
    {
        // Just for testing, no real code here.
        return 0L;
    }

    static void testNull(@NonNull Long value) {
    }

    static void test()
    {
        final Long something = getLong("somekey", 1L);
        testNull(something);
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't show any error. Only when the `@Contract` annotation is removed will the IDE warn about the call to `testNull()` with a potentially null value.

Comment: Why even have a default value? Just let the method caller handle it the same way you do. If `value` is null, return null. `map.optLong("key") ?: 6L`

Comment: Also, consider using `string.toLongOrNull()` instead of `Long.valueOf(string)` it handles bad formats automatically.

Comment: @killjoy Using null as a default can mean several things, not just no value found. If he decides that use of a null default is good for this use case, then one could add make the `default` param default to `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by making the function generic.

```
fun <T: Long?> Map<String, String>.optLong(key: String, default: T): T 
{
    // do something.
    return default
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val nullable: Long? = 0L
    val notNullable: Long = 0L

    someMap.optLong(nullable) // Returns type `Long?`
    someMap.optLong(notNullable) // Returns type `Long`
}
```

This works because `Long?` is a supertype of `Long`. The type will normally be inferred in order to return a nullable or non-nullable type based on the parameters.

This will "tell the Kotlin compiler that when the default value is not null, the result won't be null either."

Comment: The return branch forces me to make an unchecked cast of `Long!` to `T` but since that's inside the helper function I don't mind.

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamHankiewicz What did you end up with for your method signature? I didn't think `Long!` needed to be cast to `T` since it's a subtype (kind of) of `T`

Comment: I copied your example and replaced ``do something`` with the code above.

Comment: This works for Kotlin callers, where the return value is dependent on the _declared_ type of the passed argument. But `@Contract` also takes other things into account, for example whether you have already checked if a `Long?` is actually null or can be cast to `Long!`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61369632/231078) for an explanation of how to make `@Contract` work with Kotlin extension functions (and it also allows it to work from Java callers as well)

Answer (score 2):

It's a pity that you can't do this, in Kotlin 1.2 or below.

However, Kotlin is working on `contract dsl` which is unannounced yet, which is not available ATM (since they're declared `internal` in the stdlib) but you can use some hacks to use them in your codes (by compiling a stdlib yourself, make all of them public).

You can see them in the stdlib ATM:

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
    return block(this)
}
```

Maybe there will be something like

```
contract {
   when(null != default) implies (returnValue != null)
}
```

in the future that can solve your problem.

### Workaround

Personally I'd recommend you to replace `default`'s type with a NotNull `Long` and call it like

```
val nullableLong = blabla
val result = nullableLong?.let { oraora.optLong(mudamuda, it) }
```

`result` is `Long?` and it's null only when `nullableLong` is null.

Comment: That's cool, I had no idea that was something they were working on.

Answer (score 1):

`@Contract` does work with Kotlin extension functions, it just needs to be changed to work with the compiled bytecode. An extension function is compiled in bytecode as a static method:

```kotlin
fun ClassA?.someMethod(arg: ClassB): ClassC? {
    return this?.let { arg.someMethod(it)!! }
}
```

Java will see this as nullable, so it will require you to null-check the result. But the real contract is:  "if ClassA is null, returns null; otherwise if ClassA is not null, returns non-null".  But IntelliJ does not understand that (at least from a Java source).

When that method gets compiled to Java bytecode it's actually:

```java
@Nullable static ClassC someMethod(@Nullable ClassA argA, @NonNull ClassB argB) {}
```

So you need to account for the synthetic first argument, when writing your `@Contract`:

```kotlin
@Contract("null, _ -> null; !null, _ -> !null")
fun ClassA?.someMethod(arg: ClassB): ClassC? {...}
```

After that, IntelliJ will understand the contract of the static method, and will understand that the return value's nullability is dependent on the first argument's nullness.

So the short version, as it pertains to this question is, you just need to add an extra `_` argument to the Contract, to represent the "this" argument:

```kotlin
@Contract("_, _, !null -> !null") // args are: ($this: Map, key: String, default: Long?)
fun Map<String, String>.optLong(key: String, default: Long?): Long? {
```

Comment: I just tried this but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working. I'm still getting `Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver`.